# Understanding Sinon Spies: What happens when a spy-wrapped method is called?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, sinon

When I wrap the method of a class into a Sinon-spy like this:

```
sinon.spy(myObject, "myMethod")
```

What happens within the spy?

I guess the spy-object has a reference which points to "myObject.myMethod".

**What happens when the method becomes call?**

I know that the spy logs information about the invocation like times of invocations, the used parameter etc.

But does the myMethod **really** become invoked?

I mean: Passes the spy object the invocation further? **Does the spy-object act as proxy?** Or does it only log the information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From a simple test it seems that sinon spy does call the original method:

```
it('does a thing', function() {
    const el = {};
    el.thing = function() { console.log('thing'); }
    sinon.spy(el, 'thing');
    el.thing();
    console.log(el.thing.called);
});

// prints:
// thing
// true
```

It also seems like that from [the docs](http://sinonjs.org/releases/v4.2.2/spies/):

> sinon.spy(object, "method") creates a spy that wraps the existing function object.method. **The spy will behave exactly like the original method** (including when used as a constructor), but you will have access to data about all calls.

Comment: Awesome. So it acts like a proxy indeed. Why haven't I had that simple idea myself. :)) Anyway: Thanks a big bunch.